# Creating a send and receive TCP-IP connection in labVIEW

Tags: tcp, connection, server, client, labview

I am trying to create a send and receive connection in labVIEW. I used the following structure to send and receive. This structure is used to difference port numbers to send and receive respectively which it is not working. Let me note that I also used one port to send and receive which hasn't worked. I am experimenting both VIs in my PC. Could it be the reason? [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRIXC.jpg [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJHGn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open LabVIEW example finder from help -> search for **TCP** open Simple TCP.lvproj and explore example code. This could be good starting point for you. [image]